# Handle JSON Response that comes without 'root' element with RestEasy

Tags: java, json, rest, resteasy

I invoke some web service (constructed in Ruby) and get JSON response like this:

```json
{
    "error_code": "02",
    "message": "Param not valid",
    "field_name": "title"
}
```

To model that response object in Java I try with:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class Response {
    
    private String error_code;
    private String message;
    private String field_name;
    
    public String getError_code() {
        return error_code;
    }
    public void setError_code(String error_code) {
        this.error_code = error_code;
    }
    
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    
    public String getField_name() {
        return field_name;
    }
    public void setField_name(String field_name) {
        this.field_name = field_name;
    }
            
}
```

... and to read the response of a WS invocation in my WS Client I try:

```java
Response response = responseWs.readEntity(Response.class);
```

... but I get following exception:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshalException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException 
 - with linked exception: 
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; columnNumber: 0 unexpected element ... Expected elements are
```

That is because my code is trying to handle JSON response object like this (with some 'root' element):

```json
{
    "response":
    {
        "error_code": "02",
        "message": "Param not valid",
        "field_name": "title"
    }       
}
```

Does somebody knows how can I solve this situation, on my side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this snippet solves the issue:

```
String responseAsString = responseWs.readEntity(String.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode pathNode = mapper.readTree(responseAsString);
Response response = mapper.convertValue(pathNode, Response.class);
```

Comment: its possible that you show me a snippet that works with xml instead of json?

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippet you posted

> Response response = responseWs.readEntity(Response.class);

I would recommend using some other name for your entity object. `Response` class is also used by jaxrs framework itself.

I am assuming you are using `RestEasyClient` to call this (external) service to receive JSON. If it is understood that the response from this service is in JSON, you can use JSON (jackson) marshaller/unmarshaller instead of JAXB. Assuming you already have "resteasy-client" dependency available on your classpath. The maven form of this dependency looks as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

1. Change the name of the DTO to something `ExternalServiceResponse`
2. While executing `GET` request you specify explicitly the response media type

```
Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
ExternalServiceResponse result = response.readEntity(ExternalServiceResponse.class)
```

3. Finally I don't see why you need to specify `@XmlRootElement` annotation on your DTO

```
public class ExternalServiceResponse implements Serializeable {

    private String error_code;
    private String message;
    private String field_name;

    public String getError_code() {
        return error_code;
    }
    public void setError_code(String error_code) {
        this.error_code = error_code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getField_name() {
        return field_name;
    }
    public void setField_name(String field_name) {
        this.field_name = field_name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There where you configured JAXB (a properties file or a config method) you should set 
`jaxbUnmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false)`

Comment: I use RestEasy. What is the package name of 'UnmarshallerProperties'? Thanks!

Comment: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.UnmarshallerProperties

Comment: Any other alternatives appreciated as long as we prefer avoiding Glassfish libraries for now